# props value which depends on other props doesn't update

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I wonder why the `color` props doesn't update when `isSelected` changes to be equal to `value`.

**My component**

```js
const MyChip = (props: any) => {
  const enhancedProps = {
    ...props,
    variant: 'outlined',
    label: props.title,
    color: (props.isSelected === props.value) ? 'primary' : 'default'
  }

  return <MuiChip {...enhancedProps} />
}
```

**1st render**

```js
{
  isSelected: ""
  onChange: e => {…}
  onClick: () => handleClick(option.value)
  title: "My Input"
  value: "my_value"
}
```

After a click on the `MyChip` component, here are the props

**2nd render**

```js
{
  isSelected: "my_value"
  onChange: e => {…}
  onClick: () => handleClick(option.value)
  title: "My Input"
  value: "my_value"
}
```

However, the `color` props in my `MyChip` component doesn't update and a 2nd click on the component doesn't trigger a render anymore.

Comment: Where is `baseProps` declared and where are you using `enhancedProps`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo. Both are `enhancedProps`. But the issue remains

Comment: `enhancedProps` contained special character so that is why it didn't work.

Comment: You have a typo `props.isSelected` not `props.isSeleced`, vote for typo close

Comment: @DennisVash that’s what I believed to be a special character because I tried to re-write the enhancedProps object and it worked. Thank tou